# MPAndroidCharts round corners Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

I have tried rounding the corners of the pie chart and trying to reduce the size of the light part slightly, with no success at all. If anyone knows how to do it, I would be very grateful.

This is what I did:

[Pie chart result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10jKJ.png)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {




override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //declare a function for pie chart activity
    setUpSelectionPieChart()
}

private fun setUpSelectionPieChart() {

    //Create a dataset
    val dataArray = ArrayList<PieEntry>()
    dataArray.add(PieEntry(38f))
    dataArray.add(PieEntry(14f))
    dataArray.add(PieEntry(14f))
    dataArray.add(PieEntry(34f))
    val dataSet = PieDataSet(dataArray, "")
    dataSet.valueTextSize=20f
    dataSet.valueTextColor=Color.WHITE

    //Color set for the chart
    val colorSet = java.util.ArrayList<Int>()
    colorSet.add(Color.rgb(255,107,107))  //red
    colorSet.add(Color.rgb(173,232,244))  // blue
    colorSet.add(Color.rgb(216,243,220))  // green
    colorSet.add(Color.rgb(255,230,109))  // Yellow
    dataSet.setColors(colorSet)
    dataSet.sliceSpace = 10F


    val data = PieData(dataSet)

    //Personal Configuration
    pieChart.transparentCircleRadius = 95F
    pieChart.isRotationEnabled = false
    pieChart.setDrawRoundedSlices(false)




    //chart description
    pieChart.description.text = "Pie chart"
    pieChart.description.textSize = 20f

    //Chart data and other styling
    pieChart.data = data
    pieChart.centerTextRadiusPercent = 0f
    pieChart.isDrawHoleEnabled = true
    pieChart.legend.isEnabled = false
    pieChart.description.isEnabled = false




}
```

This is what I want to have:

[Screenshot of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woye0.png)